# Copy several sheets to a new workbook. However got 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba

My code is as below. I googled a lot about 1004 error for vba in Excel 2013 and followed MS suggestion that open, save as and close [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210684).

Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

```
Sub SaveAs(FilePath As String)

Dim thisWb As Workbook, wbTemp As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error GoTo Whoa

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook
Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add

On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In wbTemp.Worksheets
    ws.Delete
Next

wbTemp.SaveAs FilePath, 51
wbTemp.Close SaveChanges:=True
Set wbTemp = Nothing
Set wbTemp = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)

On Error GoTo 0

For Each ws In thisWb.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "data" And ws.Name <> "parameters" Then
        ws.Copy After:=wbTemp.Sheets(1)
    End If
Next

wbTemp.Sheets(1).Delete
wbTemp.SaveAs FilePath, 51

LetsContinue:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: What line throws the 1004 and what is the 1004 saying? The error messages differ for 1004s.

Comment: What is the value of `filepath` that is being passed into the sub as a parameter? If the new workbook cannot be saved with that path and name then it cannot be reopened.

Comment: Do **NOT** name your sub procedure the same as an actual command. The [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) should be considered a **reserved word** and never used to name something of your own creation.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Sub SaveAs(FilePath As String)

Dim thisWb As Workbook, wbTemp As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

On Error GoTo Whoa

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook
Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add

On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In wbTemp.Worksheets
    ws.Delete
Next

wbTemp.SaveAs FilePath, 51
wbTemp.Close SaveChanges:=True
Set wbTemp = Nothing
Set wbTemp = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)

On Error GoTo 0

Dim counter As Integer
counter = 0

For Each ws In thisWb.Sheets
    If ws.Name <> "data" And ws.Name <> "parameters" Then
        ws.Copy After:=wbTemp.Sheets(1)
        counter = counter + 1
        If iCounter Mod 50 = 0 Then
            wbTemp.Close SaveChanges:=True
            Set wbTemp = Nothing
            Set wbTemp = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
        End If
    End If
Next

wbTemp.Sheets(1).Delete
wbTemp.SaveAs FilePath, 51

LetsContinue:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: does your FilePath include the name and the extension of the file?

Comment: And rename your sub: Sub WBSaveAs(FilePath as String)

Comment: @Kathara It's mainly OP's code, I made only a few changes. I think your comments should go to Tony's question.

Comment: @Kathara No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I use an array to copy it once instead of copying sheets one by one:

```
Dim group As Variant, s As Integer, path As String

ReDim group(0)
For s = 1 To Sheets.Count    'or use "For Each s in ActiveWorkbook.Sheets"
    If Sheets(s).Name Like "string" Then
        group(UBound(group)) = Sheets(s).Name
        ReDim Preserve group(UBound(group) + 1)
    End If
Next s

If Application.CountA(group) > 1 Then
    ReDim Preserve group(UBound(group) - 1)
    Sheets(group).Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs path & "Document" & "_" & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End If
```